# eclipse "find all references" - how do i limit file types for this search

Tags: eclipse

when using Eclipse can press Ctrl+alt+G to find all references.

How do i limit file types for this search,
I.e. search will be done only for *.c files, for example

tried everything

Answer (score 0):

You can do Ctrl+H -> File Search. Paste the string you want to search in 'Containing text'. In 'File name patterns' you can use *.c.